# clicking on link button in gridview does not show the details in detailsview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a grid view and a details view. In that grid view I have a link button column in the first column. When I click on the link button column it has to show the corresponding row values in the details view. I am using separate data sources for details view and grid view.

This is the grid view code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcegridview" Height="533px" Width="316px" 
    style="text-align: left" EnableCallBack="false" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" > 
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
            <HeaderTemplate>    
                <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="DCN"></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkname" runat="server" SortExpression="DCN"
                            Text='<%#Eval("DCN") %>' CausesValidation="false"
                            CommandName='<%#Eval("DCN")%>' OnClick = "Link_buttonClick">
                   linkbutton
            </asp:LinkButton>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                               
        <asp:BoundField DataField="priority" HeaderText="priority" 
                        SortExpression="priority" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Datasource for gridview:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourcegridview" runat="server" 
                   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectDBString %>" 
                   SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [MASTERETMTABLE] WHERE ([DCN] = @DCN)">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="BAT" Name="DCN" Type="String" />
     </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Details view:

```
<asp:Panel ID="paneldetails" runat="server" BackColor="#CCCCCC" 
           Visible="False" >
    <asp:DetailsView ID="detailsvw" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
                     DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcedetailsview" Width="424px"> 
         <Fields>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="DCN" HeaderText="DCN" SortExpression="DCN" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="PRIORITY" HeaderText="PRIORITY" 
                             SortExpression="PRIORITY" />
         </Fields
    </asp:DetailsView>
</asp:Panel>
```

and this is my datasource for details view

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourcedetailsview" runat="server" 
                   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectDBString %>" 
                   SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [MASTERETMTABLE] WHERE ([DCN] = @DCN)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="DCN" ControlID="GridView2"/>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is the code behind file for the gridview page.

```
protected void Link_buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    paneldetails.Visible = true;
    detailsvw.Visible = true;
    // do I need to add any thing at here
}
```

I am not able to get the data into details view here. When I click on any cell in the first column it shows the details view in panel.

How do I get the details view to display the data from the clicked row?

Comment: Where are you setting the data source for the details view?

Comment: I have given datasource id  of the sqldatasource to detailsview datasourceid

Comment: Yeah, okay, but then you're good, right? Where are you loading the *data source related to the row*?

Comment: Why are'nt you using [RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) instead of OnClick? That way you can get the id from the clicked row.

Comment: hmm by using row command can I get all values in row

Comment: Try it, you'll be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to implement Master-Details relationship is to add the `DataKeyNames="DCN"` (pertinent to your case) to the first GridView and refer to it as a Parameter in Details form: see the sample here: http://www.vkinfotek.com/detailsview/gridview-detailsview-master-detail-example.html